# iText PDF form field values are "not appearing"

Tags: java, itext, pdf-form

I'm using iText to create pdf forms with some fields from generated by Java. The PDF form should be filled out and by clicking a send button, the values of the fields should be sent to the server in order to save them in the database. My problem is that the form fields aren't shown while filling them out. It seems like the font is transparent, even when I select the text which I typed in those fields, the text doesn't appear. But by sending the from back to the server all data is save properly. Here is the part of cpde which I'm using to set font parameters while the creating form:

```
PdfWriter writer = stamper.getWriter();

String fieldName = df.getFofdName();
String value = formfieldValues.get(fieldName);

TextField tf = new TextField(writer, fieldName);
tf.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
if (showBorders) {
    tf.setBorderColor(Color.BLACK);
}
if (isMultiline) {
    tf.setOptions(BaseField.MULTILINE);
}

BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("C:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
tf.setExtensionFont(BaseFont.createFont());
ArrayList<BaseFont> list = new ArrayList<BaseFont>();
list.add(bf);
tf.setSubstitutionFonts(list);
tf.setText(value);
stamper.addAnnotation(tf.getTextField(), 1);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Preview on Mac? (Because what you describe is a known problem in Preview that doesn't occur with Adobe Reader.)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie No, I'm using Adobe Reader 11.0.3 and Windows 8

Comment: @BrunoLowagie BTW is there any alternative solutions to make visiblethe text in Adobe Reader? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see you adding the form field to a page of the stamper.

Comment: @mkl I'm new in using iText, can you please provide me with example? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand: you're new, yet you're familiar with extension and substitution fonts? I'm pretty sure you don't need such fonts. Where did you find that code sample? Also: I didn't think of what @mkl said because it seemed as if you've cut many things from the snippet. I've added a line to your question.

Comment: @mkl I suppose the fields are added, because the values reach the server. In any case: this is a problem that can only be solved if we get a http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Dozent Do you actually have the `stamper.addAnnotation` call (with an appropriate page number of course) Bruno added to your question? Please provide a sample PDF to inspect or even better a SSCCE as Bruno requested.